# Focus an item in ListView with VirtualMode enabled

Tags: c#, .net, listview, setfocus, virtualmode

I have a ListView in VirtualMode.

I need a way to set focus to specific item.

The `FocusedItem` is not good for the VirtualMode, I need a way to set FocusedIndex or something like that, but didn't see any property like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `Focused` property on the `ListViewItem` directly.

So, to set the 11th row to be focused:

```
this.lvVirtual.Items[10].Focused = true;
```

Comment: I once tried to change the icon of a virtual item this way without success, and then stopped use `.Items` to access virtual items. Thanks for the example, worked for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said `ListView` is in `VirtualMode`. `Items` collection is not accessible here.

Try to raise an event `VirtualItemsSelectionRangeChanged`